# Error while executing hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04

Being a beginner to hadoop,I started to try out configuring a single node hadoop cluster in ubuntu. After installation and configuration, I worked with the example part with hadoop and it have thrown the following error

```
hduser1@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-   examples-2.2.0.jar pi 2 5
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

I have used Java-7-oracle and Ubuntu 12.04 and followed this post to install and configure hadoop:
    http://codesfusion.blogspot.in/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message means that while the runtime was able to find the class `ProgramDriver`, the function `run()` is not present.

The most likely reason for this is that you're running an old version of Hadoop that exposed a difference interface in `ProgramDriver`.  About a year ago this method was [renamed](https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/commit/d5373b9c550a355d4e91330ba7cc8f4c7c3aac51) to `run()` after being called `driver()`.

The fix for that would be making sure you're running a recent version of Hadoop.