# Unable to run basic example for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Hadoop version 2.9.0, Java - 1.8.0_162
When trying to run the example given here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html, under standalone operation, I get the following error:

```
$ bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.0.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

I am new to hadoop and not sure how to fix this. I have set the JAVA_HOME in hadoop-env.sh. I am pretty sure that I am using the correct compatible versions of java and hadoop.
Any help will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Nish,

The error message means that while the runtime was able to find the class ProgramDriver, the function run() is not present.

The most likely reason for this is that you're running an old version of Hadoop that exposed a difference interface in ProgramDriver. About a year ago this method was renamed to run() after being called driver().

The fix for that would be making sure you're running a recent version of Hadoop.

For your reference please check following links they have asked same question.

[Error while executing hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283412/error-while-executing-hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2-2-0-jar)

[Can the hadoop programm which write under the hadoop-2.2.0 run in hadoop-1.2.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825588/can-the-hadoop-programm-which-write-under-the-hadoop-2-2-0-run-in-hadoop-1-2-1?rq=1)